# SQL query: Get the most expensive product ordered in each month of 2011

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I don't understand how to "combine" two tables so that I can generate an answer to this.

Basically I have a CAP database and I'm only concerned with two tables:

```
ORDERS (ordno, month, year, cid, aid, pid, qty, dollars)
PRODUCTS (pid, pname, city, quantity, price)
```

I know that i need to generate a new table like the following to get the answer:

```
Temp (month, year, pname, price)
```

The way I tried to do it is:

```
Temp = Select * from (

(Select month, year from Orders)

join

(Select price, pname from Products)

on

orders.pid = products.pid )
```

The above query gives me an error that I don't understand: Every derived table must have its own alias.

The next step i'm pretty sure is:

```
Answer = select max(price), pname, month from Temp where year = 2011 group by month;
```

I am very new to SQL. If you guys could help me that would be great. If there is a website that can help me learn SQL better please let me know. Thanks!

EDIT: also if there is more than one product that has max price then you need to list all of them for that month.

EDIT 2: SOLVED THANKS!!

Comment: if there are 2 products having the same price then the logic would differ. and I also see qty field assuming its quantitiy. would it effect on price ?

Comment: the query specifies that its the most expensive product, not the most expensive order. your only concerned with the price of the product itself not how many of it you ordered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**

If the price of the product ever changes, you will not get a meaningful result.

```
SELECT P.pid, P.price, O.month, P.pname FROM 
products as P
JOIN orders AS O ON
    P.pid = O.pid       
JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(P.price) AS price
        , O.month           
    FROM
        orders AS O
        LEFT JOIN products AS P ON
            O.pid = P.pid
    WHERE
        O.year = 2011
    GROUP BY
        O.month
) AS MX ON
    MX.month = O.month
    AND O.year = 2011
    AND P.price = MX.price
```

FYI This is how you give a derived table an alias.

```
(Select month, year from Orders) AS myAlias
```

Comment: It only gives you the highest price, not the product it belongs to.

Comment: @GolezTrol, read the question, this is the structure the posters wants `(month, year, pname, price)`

Comment: @GolezTrol, if it makes you happy I added the product id.

Comment: hey mike thanks for your help but there is no field Orders.pname did you mean Products.pname?

Comment: also i don't understand why but your query is returning products for each month that aren't the most expensive including the most expensive product.

Comment: i got the answer. just had to change the group by clause to "group by month"

Comment: @user1013197:  The above query will return the maximum prices for EVERY product in a month, not just the maximum-priced product(s) for that month.  I'm a bit confused by this, because this is similar to what I had before, but you commented it was wrong...

Comment: @Briguy37, you are correct, I didn't read it very carefully.  I would delete my answer so you could get credit.  But I can't delete an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you are trying to do:

```
SELECT o.month, o.year, p.price, p.pname
from orders o 
INNER JOIN products p on p.pid = o.pid
INNER JOIN (
    select o.month, o.year, max(p.price) price 
    from orders o 
    left outer join products p on p.pid = o.pid
    group by o.month, o.year
) maxInfo ON (o.month = maxInfo.month) and (o.year = maxInfo.year) and (p.price = maxInfo.price)
```

Comment: could you explain how your query works? i'm not sure what left outer join is.

Comment: user1013197: In this case, "left outer join" means "for each order, get the product(s) that have the same product id".

Comment: thanks for explaining. i tried this query though and its giving multiple products for the same month including ones that don't have the max price.. i'm not sure why because you specified it should be the maximum.

Comment: @user1013197:  Ok, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  The query above gives the max price for every product in each month and year.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice what you changed to fix it?

Comment: @user1013197:  Working on it :)

Comment: @user1013197:  Fixed it now.  Give that a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: you dont have to do "max(p.price)" in first line since you already did (p.price = maxInfo.price). if you take another max it would bug the query itself

Comment: hey it doesn't work. i honestly don't even know whats going on. but mike's answer works when i changed it to "group by orders.month" thanks for your help though

Comment: @user1013197:  From what I understand of your requirements (only get the max-priced product(s) in a month), mikerobi's query shouldn't work just by changing the group-by.

Comment: @Briguy37: upvoted you since yours is the real answer to these kind of problem. (Your only mistake is using left outer join instead of simple inner join on products, its really not necessary)

Comment: @user1013197: mikerobi's query is a solution when there are no 2 products sharing the same price as maximum of month as far as I see, this one ,although it's not efficient, would solve the same priced item problem.

Comment: @frail: Thanks again, you're right that the left join just added extra overhead in this case.  That is now replaced with the proper INNER JOIN.

Answer (score -1):

The error is because the sub tables your building don't have an alias.  the answer to your error would be fixed with the following I believe:

```
Temp = Select * from (  
(Select month, year from Orders)ords
join  
(Select price, pname from Products)prods  
on  ords.pid = prods.pid )
```

you are building a table on the fly and then aliasing it to ords or prods.

Comment: This would eliminate the errors, but doesn't address the fact that this is a terrible way to join 2 tables.